# Delphi with [DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I try to compile apps for Linux using Delphi 10.4 and FMXLinux, guess my installation is correct and complete.
Compiling my first app for Linux I get this error message :

```
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot open C:\\Users\\Franz\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\SDKs\\ubuntu22.04.sdk/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
[DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:01.1
```

the folder  is not present on my computer , but this folder is existing :

```
"C:\Users\Franz\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\ubuntu22.04.sdk\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

Q1 :  what did I do wrong during installation, why are *.so files are stored inside a different folder ?

Q2 : what is the  best way to fix it ? Just rename the folder - or will this create many other failures ?

Comment: When installing Delphi, are you sure you selected Linux platform? If not, from the IDE, select Menu / Tools / Manage Platform to add Linux platform, or run the installer again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install PAServer into Linux first.

in your windows go to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\PAServer

there you will find a tar.gz file.
copy it to linux and untar there.

Run ./paserver (you will be asked about a password. leave it empty). when running your will see the port it is listening.

back to windows in your Delphi go to
tools -> options -> deployment -> Connection Profile Manager
click add and select Linux platform and name it.
use the the linux IP where paserver were installed and the same port.

After that go to
tools -> options -> deployment -> SDK Manager

click add and select the platform and profile desired.
It will install all needed files to compile in Linux.

After that your profile is installed and your Delphi ready to compile to linux.

PS. To debug linux app you need to keep paserver running inside linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to .

Reinstall g++ on host machine

```
"sudo apt-get install g++"
```

And then update SDK on Delphi/Tools/Options/SDK Manager/Linux
configuratin with "Update Local cache"

[Rad Studio Options for SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYGhE.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).